# Why jQuery .on() doesn't handle javascript dynamically created events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I have a vanilla Javascript system triggering a `change` event on a dropdown:

```
const event = new Event('change');
select.dispatchEvent(event);
```

It works perfectly handling the event through `addEventListener()` or `$('select').on()`
but it doesn't work if `.on()` function is set to target dynamic elements:

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function() {
    console.log('should');
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is for a constructed event to *not* bubble up the DOM tree. If you want that, you need to explicitly ask for it:

```
const event = new Event("change", { bubbles: true });
```

If the event doesn't bubble, it won't make it up to the `document` level and the delegated handler won't be invoked.

Comment: THAT is what I was missing. Thanks Pointy!